# Erro de acentuação no editor de IDE - Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, netbeans, acentuação

Estou com problemas de acentuação nas IDE's 'Netbeans' e 'Android Studio'.

Meu sistema operacional é linux elementary os [elementary OS 0.4 Loki]

**Apenas** nas ides os caracteres de acentuação não são digitados. Não se trata de um problema de encode.

Por exemplo, quando digito "não, café, vôo", as palavras ficam assim: "nao, cafe, voo" ... como se não estivesse colocado os acentos.

**Saída do locales -a**

```
bg_BG.utf8
C
ca_AD.utf8
ca_ES.utf8
ca_ES.utf8@valencia
ca_FR.utf8
ca_IT.utf8
cs_CZ.utf8
C.UTF-8
da_DK.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
hu_HU.utf8
id_ID.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
ko_KR.utf8
nb_NO.utf8
nl_AW
nl_AW.utf8
nl_BE.utf8
nl_NL.utf8
pl_PL.utf8
POSIX
pt_BR
pt_BR.iso88591
pt_BR.utf8
pt_PT.utf8
sv_FI.utf8
sv_SE.utf8
th_TH.utf8
tr_CY.utf8
tr_TR.utf8
uk_UA.utf8
vi_VN
vi_VN.utf8
zh_HK.utf8
zh_TW.utf8
```

**Configuração Netbeans**

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Atualizações: O IDE NetBeans está atualizado para a versão NetBeans 8.2 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
System: Linux version 4.4.0-57-generic running on amd64; utf-8; pt_BR (nb)
User directory: /home/marcela/.netbeans/8.2
Cache directory: /home/marcela/.cache/netbeans/8.2
```

**Configuração Android Studio**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tentei muitas coisas, mas não consegui solucionar este problema. No entanto, quando abro o android studio pelo terminal (como root) a acentuação funciona. [O Netbeans não consegui testar dessa forma].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente faça o teste com o seguinte comando:

```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2
```

Caso funcione e queira fazer isto ficar funcionando de um maneira permanente, edite o seguinte arquivo:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

e o altere para ficar na seguinte configuração:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="br"
XKBVARIANT="abnt2"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Salve o arquivo e faça um reboot e fecha se ficou permanente.

Comment: Obrigada. 
agora está funcionando :D

Answer (score 1):

Como resolvi o problema de acentuação do Android Studio no elementary OS.

Primeiramente, isso é problema do elementary OS (ou do Linux que você estiver utilizando) e não do Android Studio. Portanto, não adianta reinstalar, não vai resolver!

Resolvendo...

No elementary OS
Passo 1: Instale o "iBus QT4".
Em um terminal:

```
sudo apt install ibus-qt4
```

Passo 2: Abra o iBus

```
ibus-setup
```

Passo 3: Na segunda aba, "Método de Entrada", veja se tem a opção "Português - Português(Brasil)".

3.A) Se não tiver a entrada "Português - Português(Brasil)", clique no botão ao lado "Adicionar", procure "Português - Português(Brasil)" e adicione. Siga para o passo 3.B;

3.B) Se tiver a entrada "Português - Português(Brasil)", exclua a entrada "English" e deixe somente a "Português". Feche o iBus e vá para o passo 4;

Passo 4: Após fechar o iBus, no terminal digite:

```
ibus-daemon -drx
```

Agora faça um teste. Isso vai resolver o problema até a próxima reinicialização. Para manter funcionando "4éva", você precisa colocar o comando do passo 4 na inicialização automática (no elementary OS).